# Delete old files from a big folder with powershell

Tags: powershell, delete-file

I have a very big folder (contains subfolders in few levels, millions of files in total). I want to only deletes files that are older than X days (eg 10 days).

My script below works fine for a folder with thousands of files, but is not working for that big folder. Any idea to optimize this? Thanks !

```
$tmpList = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Recurse
$fileObjects = $tmpList `
        | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -le $maxDateToProcess) } `
        | Sort-Object -Property "LastWriteTime" -Descending
$allFiles = $fileObjects | Select -ExpandProperty "FullName"
Remove-Item -Path $allFiles
```

Comment: robocopy is a good bet for this sort of thing. one not-so-obvious way to do what you want is to mirror the selected files against a blank dir. the `/MinAge:##` option will _exclude_ files that are newer than ## days OR ## date. ///// mirroring against a non-existent dir will delete the files ... [*grin*] plus, the `/L` option will just show you what it _would_ do, so you can get a good idea of how well it will work. ///// you may still need to start with one of the subdirs to keep the run-time reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following command to delete files that haven’t been modified in the last 30 days and press Enter:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "C:\path\to\folder" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnnBlade for the answer, but we don't need to filter for file / folder ?

Comment: If you have any specific extensions that you need to exclude or include then you can use `-Exclude` / `-Include`. Also for directories you can use `|?{ $_.PSIsContainer }` .. So all are possible depending on the scenario

Comment: "get-childitem" has a parameter 'itemtype' where you can select if you want files or directories